# Prove that a number $a$ is rational if and only if there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $[ka]=ka$; likewise for $[k! a]= k! a$

Tags: rational-numbers

How can I go about proving the following problem:

Prove that a number $a$ is rational if and only if there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $[ka]=ka$. Prove that a number $a$ is rational if and only if there exists $k$ such that $[k! a]= k! a$

Comment: I cannot see where Farey fractions appear

Comment: @mau: I have removed "Farey fractions" from the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following chain of reasoning proves both parts of both problems:

---

If $a$ is rational, then there are integers $p,q$ with $a=p/q$.

If $a=p/q$, then $qa=p$, so $[qa]=[p]=p=qa$.

If $[ka]=ka$, then $ka\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $(ka)(k-1)!\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $[k!a]=k!a$.

If $[k!a]=k!a$, then $k!a=t\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $a=t/k!$, a ratio of two integers, so $a$ is rational.